# Pygame screen blur

Tags: python, pygame, blur

So I am making a game with multiple parts using pygame and it has a "drunk" component to it. My goal is to make it so that the more "drunk" the player is, the screen will look more blurry accordingly.

[Here is a hack provided for blurring a surface](http://www.akeric.com/blog/?p=720)

But that does not work for the whole screen, which is what I need.

**How could I go about blurring the entire screen?**

Comment: abarnet already answered this question, but if you want to see a blurred screen in action, take a look at [this](http://hg.barrelburst.net/pymissile/overview) game I startet a while ago. It uses the technique described in your link.

Answer (score 3):

> How could I go about blurring the entire screen?

When you do [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) (or some other function to get the game screen*), what you get back *is* a `Surface`.

If you're following the tutorials, you've probably stored it in a variable named `screen`. Just use that as your surface.

Or you can always just draw to an off-screen surface, transform that, and blit to the screen from the transformed version.

Also, you might want to consider using `surfarray`; you can probably do a much better blur than just anti-aliased pixelization with about the same amount of code and less CPU work…

---

* The game screen may be the whole monitor screen, for a full-screen game, or the window, for a windowed game. Either way, if that's the thing you want to blur, that's the `Surface` you use. If you wanted to blur the entire monitor screen from a windowed game, that wouldn't be possible, because you don't have a handle to that… but from comments, that isn't what you want.

Comment: damn you beat me to it :)

Comment: the game is not full screen...why don't I have a handle to it?

Comment: @RyanSaxe: Well, you didn't ask `pygame` for one. And that's because there's no way to do so. And that's because SDL doesn't give pygame a way to do so. And that's because most windowing systems won't let a non-full-screen window take control of the whole screen.

Comment: I don't want control of the whole screen...I only want to blur the window

Comment: @RyanSaxe: Then that _window_, rather than the full screen, is your `Surface`. Otherwise, everything is the same. (I'll edit the answer to make it clearer.)

Comment: OH okay...so I used the method in the link I provided, but it did not create a blur on the window...I applied it to the `screen` as suggested and it either does nothing, or if I reset the screen equal to the blur, it does not blur and nothing moves either

Comment: @RyanSaxe: Reading the blog post… it returns a new surface with the blurred version of the surface you gave it. So, you will have to [`blit`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) that back to the screen.

Comment: it says i can't blit it to the screen...`self.screen.blit(surf,self.screen)
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38061/discussion-between-ryan-saxe-and-abarnert)

Comment: You can use a windowed mode + `pygame.NOFRAME` for "borderless mode". Which looks full screen, no GUI chrome, yet it's actually windowed.